# Updating the table nulls with values from another table with a priority rank

Tags: sql, database, teradata

Please help me writing an Teardata SQL query to to update NULL values in Table1 with Store from Table 2 , however it should be in order as per ran

The final result as per the expected output in the final table.

The store names can not repeat under Store1,Store2,Store 3 for a same ID.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not just some sample and you actually got only a few possible values and the ranking is fixed you can do some brute force CASEs:

```
select id,
   store1,
   
   coalesce(store2
            ,case when 'Apple'     not in store1 then 'Apple'
                  when 'Wall Mart' not in store1 then 'Wall Mart'
                  when 'Costco'    not in store1 then 'Costco'
             end) as store2_,  
   
   coalesce(store3
            ,case when 'Apple'     not in (store1, store2_) then 'Apple'
                  when 'Wall Mart' not in (store1, store2_) then 'Wall Mart'
                  when 'Costco'    not in (store1, store2_) then 'Costco'
             end) as store3_
                  
from mytab
order by 1
;
```

Can be extended